# Intermittent ability to login to my router. Unplugging the WAN allows me, while connected to WAN does not

Tags: windows, router, login

**Problem:**

Cannot log into my router: @ IP 192.168.1.1

As a result of this, I cannot log into my NAS either.

I have internet. PC to router is a problem.

***I can do both (above) when I unplug the WAN (Ethernet from modem to router).***

**My system:**

- Window 7.
- Nighthawk R7000p, NetGear router.

**What I've tried so far:**

- ipconfig /release, renew, flushdns
- "Back in time my machine to another date".
- Unplug router. Allows me to login, then blocks me a few minutes later.
- Check all connections, unplug, plug.
- Rebooted PC.
- Disabled Firewall
- Factory reset.
- Factory 30/30/30 reset.
- A Cycled reboot. Thought it cured it, but no.

Comment: @John  Well I decided to do a reset once I figured out how to backup my settings. Did a backup. Did a factory reset. Restored settings. Still no.

Comment: Try up dating the firmware and see if that helps.  Firmware and reset are two methods that have helped me over the years,

Comment: If you're still using Windows 7 online ( you are) you should seriously consider the possibility of having some malware. And no, it won't/can't be detected by any software. It's simply the case the OS itself has remained unpatched for many years. Insisting on using it is both dumb and irresponsible.

Comment: This is only the tip of the iceberg: https://stack.watch/product/microsoft/windows-7/ and the first one is possibly relevant to you: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-17153/Microsoft-Windows-7.html

Comment: @John Yeah, I was thinking that too. I am waiting for a patch cable to arrive. Going to swap it to see if it does the trick. If not I will try the update. So weird it just stopped working so I did think that maybe an update might have caused it to stop working; which sometimes happens. That's what convinced me to do the "reset". Will try soon and let you know.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have a new install this year as my drive failed more recently.  Interesting idea though.

Comment: @ChanganAuto should change your name to "QuickDraw"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Troubleshooting:**

- ipconfig /release, renew, flushdns
- "Back in time my machine to another date".
- Unplug router, wait 30 seconds, plug back in.
- Check all connections, unplug, plug. Inspect for dust.
- Rebooted PC.
- Disabled Firewall and check connection.
- Factory reset.
- Factory 30/30/30 reset.
- Unplug WAN to see if connection is possible.
- A Cycled reboot. Thought it cured it, but no.

As this was an intermittent problem, after the above was performed it seemed to connect.

***Actions**:*

**Replaced original Ethernet cable, modem-to-router, to an updated CAT8. Although it started to maintain connection, the new line seems to be a bit quicker.**

**Also, as was mentioned in the comments: "update firmware", was accomplished during a Factory Reset.**